# Magento BestSeller Module - Summing Configurable Products And Adding Them Back In

Tags: php, mysql, magento, product, configurable

This has been bugging me for quite a while. Basically, what we are trying to achieve is in the bestsellers on our front page, to have the products listed in the amount sold. For simple products this works fine, however for configurable products they will be displayed as a quantity ordered of 0.

I somehow need to find a way to get the configurable products, find the simple products attached to them, sum the amount sold of these simple products, add this back to the configurable products ID and feed this information back in so it will list the configurable product with the right amount that has been sold.

I have placed, what I believe, the areas of code that require changing. If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated!

Collection.php

```
class Luxe_Bestsellers_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection extends Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection
{
public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '', $getComplexProducts=false)
{
    $qtyOrderedTableName = $this->getTable('sales/order_item');
    $qtyOrderedFieldName = 'qty_ordered';

    $productIdFieldName = 'product_id';

    if (!$getComplexProducts) {
        $compositeTypeIds = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getCompositeTypes();
        $productTypes = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(' AND (e.type_id NOT IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds);
    } else {
        $productTypes = '';
    }

    if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
        $dateFilter = " AND `order`.created_at BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'";
    } else {
        $dateFilter = "";
    }

    $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        array('order_items' => $qtyOrderedTableName),
        array('ordered_qty' => "SUM(order_items.{$qtyOrderedFieldName})")
    );

     $_joinCondition = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'order.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND order.state<>?', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED
     );
     $_joinCondition .= $dateFilter;
     $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('order' => $this->getTable('sales/order')),
        $_joinCondition,
        array()
     );


    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()),
            "e.entity_id = order_items.{$productIdFieldName} AND e.entity_type_id = {$this->getProductEntityTypeId()}{$productTypes}")
        ->group('e.entity_id')
        ->having('ordered_qty > 0');

    return $this;
}

}
```

List.php

```
class Luxe_Bestsellers_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'bestsellers/list_toolbar';

protected function _beforeToHtml() {
    $this->addPriceBlockType('bundle', 'bundle/catalog_product_price', 'bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml');
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();    
}

public function _toHtml()
{
    if ($this->_productCollection->count()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

public function getTimeLimit()
{
    if ($this->getData('time_limit_in_days')) {
        return intval($this->getData('time_limit_in_days'));
    } else {
        return intval(Mage::getStoreConfig('bestsellers/bestsellers/time_limit_in_days'));
    }
}

public function getBlockTitle()
{
    if ($this->getData('title')) {
        return $this->getData('title');
    } else {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('bestsellers/bestsellers/title');
    }
}

public function isShowOutOfStock() {
    return (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('bestsellers/bestsellers/show_out_of_stock');
}

public function getProductsLimit()
{
    if ($this->getData('limit')) {
        return intval($this->getData('limit'));
    } else {
        return $this->getToolbarBlock()->getLimit();
    }
}

public function getDisplayMode()
{
    return $this->getData('display_mode');
}

/**
 * Retrieve loaded category collection
 *
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $layer = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer');
        $bestsellers = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
        if ($this->getTimeLimit()) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $todayDate = $product->getResource()->formatDate(time());
            $startDate = $product->getResource()->formatDate(time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * $this->getTimeLimit());
            $bestsellers->addOrderedQty($startDate, $todayDate, true);
        } else {
            $bestsellers->addOrderedQty('', '', true);
        }

        $bestsellers->addStoreFilter()
                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                ->setPageSize($this->getProductsLimit());

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($bestsellers);

        if ($layer->getCurrentCategory()->getId() != Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()) {
            $bestsellers->addCategoryFilter($layer->getCurrentCategory());
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($bestsellers);
        }

        if (!$this->isShowOutOfStock()) {
            Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($bestsellers);
        }

        $bestsellers->getSelect()->where('order.store_id = ?', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

        $productIds = array();
        foreach ($bestsellers as $p) {
            $productIds[] = $p->getId();
        }
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
        $collection->addIdFilter($productIds)
                   ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
                   ->addMinimalPrice()
                   ->addFinalPrice();
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}

/**
 * Translate block sentence
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), 'Mage_Catalog');
    array_unshift($args, $expr);
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having this exact problem.  I'll let you know if I find a solution to it.

Comment: what version of Magento did you test the code? I tried your code but the configurable product doesn't show up at all in version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting that sample code!  I was able to use it to create a solution which should work well for both of us.

I found that configurable product sales are being summed correctly but aren't being included in the results; their child products appear instead.  My solution was to include configurable products, do a left join on the `catalog_product_super_link` table, and filter out anything that has a `parent_id`.  Here are the changes you'll need to make:

Collection.php:

```
    public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '', $getComplexProducts=false, $getComplexChildProducts = true, $getRemovedProducts = true)
    {
        $qtyOrderedTableName = $this->getTable('sales/order_item');
        $qtyOrderedFieldName = 'qty_ordered';

        $productIdFieldName = 'product_id';

        if (!$getComplexProducts) {
            $compositeTypeIds = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getCompositeTypes();
            $productTypes = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(' AND (e.type_id NOT IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds);
        } else {
            $productTypes = '';
        }

        if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
            $dateFilter = " AND `order`.created_at BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'";
        } else {
            $dateFilter = "";
        }

        $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
            array('order_items' => $qtyOrderedTableName),
            array(
                'ordered_qty' => "SUM(order_items.{$qtyOrderedFieldName})",
                'order_items_name' => 'order_items.name'
            )
        );

         $_joinCondition = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'order.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND order.state<>?', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED
         );
         $_joinCondition .= $dateFilter;
         $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
            array('order' => $this->getTable('sales/order')),
            $_joinCondition,
            array()
         );

         // Add join to get the parent id for configurables
         $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
             array('cpsl' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')),
             'cpsl.product_id = order_items.product_id',
             'cpsl.parent_id'
         );

        if(!$getComplexChildProducts)
            $this->getSelect()->having('parent_id IS NULL');

        if($getRemovedProducts)
        {
             $this->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(array('e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()),
                    "e.entity_id = order_items.{$productIdFieldName} AND e.entity_type_id = {$this->getProductEntityTypeId()}{$productTypes}")
                ->group('order_items.product_id');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->getSelect()
                ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()),
                    "e.entity_id = order_items.{$productIdFieldName} AND e.entity_type_id = {$this->getProductEntityTypeId()}{$productTypes}")
                ->group('e.entity_id');
        }


        $this->getSelect()->having('ordered_qty > 0');

        // This line is for debug purposes, in case you'd like to see what the SQL looks like
        // $x = $this->getSelect()->__toString();

        return $this;
    }
```

List.php - Find the following two lines...

```
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty($startDate, $todayDate, true);
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty('', '', true);
```

... and change them to:

```
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty($startDate, $todayDate, true, false, false);
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty('', '', true, false, false);
```

My changes added two new optional parameters, which both default to `true`, as to not break existing functionality.

- When `$getComplexChildProducts` is set to `false`, all child items of the configurable product will be removed from the results.
- `$getRemovedProducts` determines whether or not previously ordered products (which have since been deleted from Magento) should also appear.

Please note that your report statistics will need to be up-to-date in order to get accurate results.

Hope this helps!  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sounds really cool - where do I add this? I added it in the Block code in class MyExt_Block_Product_Bestsellerlist extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List .... but it doesnt seem to pickup

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code to get the simple products attached to the configurable product. I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, I haven't tried it myself.

```
$simpleProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $product);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it is much appreciated. However implementing this I am not sure how I would go about it, if anyone else could add further insight it would be greatly appreciated.